# libvirt/debian: Restrict user/domain access

Tags: debian, domain, libvirt, polkit

I'm using Debian 9, Stretch, and if I add a user to the libvirt group, that user has full access to libvirt. That's fine and dandy, but what if I want to restrict user access to certain domains?

According to [libvirt.org](https://libvirt.org/aclpolkit.html), that is possible but it seems to imply that you must use Javascript, only possible under `polkit >= .106`; however, Debian (and Ubuntu) only provide polkit (PolicyKit-1) version .105, initially released in 2012!

- Clearly Debian and Ubuntu are not liking the newer Javascript way of
  things under polkit .106 and later, this is a curiosity by itself
- Regardless, how can you really limit user/domain access in Debian
  (and Ubuntu)?

Fwiw, I'm now considering running KVM under LXD.

Comment: Have you had any success using .pkla to restrict user/domain access?